# (k8s) Warning : port is not allocated (about. nodePort Service)

Tags: kubernetes, service

Hi I’m using NodePort Service on Pod
and the configuration is like below

```
port : 8006
targetPort :8006
nodePort : 8006
```

I know the default range of nodePort is **30000~39999**
but it’s nessesary to be 8006

anyway, for that, I also add some option to the configuration of api-service like below

```
( --service-port-range = 3000~39999 )
```

after that, nodePort service up, I noticed status of service like below

```
Type: warning
Reason: PortOutOfRange
From: Portallocator-repair-controller
Messeage: Port 8006 is not within the port range 30000-32767;

Type: warning
Reason: PortNotAllocated
From: Portallocator-repair-controller
Messeage: Port 8006 is not allocated
```

is this just warning for recommendation for using 30000-32767
or
could cause serious problems on App?

Comment: check the service port if it's assigned or not, i guess won't be there as out of range maybe random.

Answer (score 0):

Nodeport is not able to use ports out of the range 30000-32767, so your solution won't work.

To use the port 8006 you either need a Ingress Route or a Load Balancer!